# slow uploading dcc.Upload component

Tags: python, plotly-dash

There is a way to make the file uploading faster with the dcc.Upload component ? In fact, for my app if the user uploads a 978 Ko file it's good and the app can parse the file fastly ( around 1-2 seconds). But for a bigger file (230 000 K) it takes around 1 min. Can I improve that ?